# duplicate entry AbsHListView in my Android Project

Tags: android, aviary

I am working on one android application, where i am using two libraries ( Aviary android sdk and PrintIO sdk)

Getting conflict in libraries and getting this error each time when compiling project :

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: it/sephiroth/android/library/widget/AbsHListView$1.class
```

I have not used such library anywhere in my project as well as i also checked in both libraries, but not found anything.

Please anyone suggest me anything why i am getting this conflict in my project?

EDIT :

Here is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        name 'maven.aviary.com'
        url uri("http://maven.aviary.com/repo/release")
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXX.XXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/librsjni.so'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    compile project(':MaterialDialog')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1.jar')
    compile project(':StaggeredGrid')
    compile project(':CustomFloatingButtonLibrary')
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile project(':image_select_lib')
    compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
    compile project(':chipsLib')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.4.3-s3.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'


    compile 'com.instabug.library:instabugsupport:1.+'
    //    compile 'com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.6.3'
    compile 'com.yalantis:phoenix:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
    compile project(':Aviary-SDK')
    compile project(':SwipyLib')
    compile project(':printio')
}
```

EDIT 2 :

I searched for library (AbsHListView) using CTRL + N and it result in following :

[image]

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Hello @EricB. Posted build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

I did a google search for the class `it/sephiroth/android/library/widget/AbsHListView$1.class` and found out it is used by the library [here](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/it/sephiroth/android/library/widget/AbsHListView.java).

Looks like one of your dependencies is using this library. If you are on Windows press CTRL + N and enter this `AbsHListView` and search. You will find the conflicting class.

**EDIT:**
Change your dependency like this:

```
compile project(':printio') {
   exclude group: 'it.sephiroth.android.library.widget'
}
```

Comment: Same errors :(  

compile (project(':printio')){
        exclude group: 'it.sephiroth.android.library.widget'
    }